# Return an array of Interfaces or extended interfaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

Not sure if the title resembles correctly my question, but I am open to suggestions.

I have the following method which returns either array of IListItem or array of other interfaces that extend that interface.

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { IWebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
import { IListItem} from "./models/IListItem";
import { IFactory } from "./IFactory";
import { INewsListItem } from "./models/INewsListItem";
import { IDirectoryListItem } from "./models/IDirectoryListItem";
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from "./models/IAnnouncementListItem";

export class ListItemFactory implements IFactory {
    private _listItems: IListItem[];
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): Promise<IListItem[]> {
        switch(listName) {
            case "GenericList":
                let items: IListItem[];
                // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json(); 
                })
                .then((json: { value: IListItem[] }) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.value));
                    return items=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            //key: v.id,
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title                        
                        }
                    ));
                });  
            case "News":
                let newsitems: INewsListItem[];
                // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Created By,Modified By,newsheader,newsbody,expiryDate`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: INewsListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: INewsListItem[] }) => {
                    return items=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            newsheader: v.newsheader,
                            newsbody: v.newsbody,
                            expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                        }
                    ));
                });
            case "Announcements":
                let announcementitems: IAnnouncementListItem[];
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }) => {
                    return items=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            announcementBody: v.announcementBody,
                            expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                        }
                    ));
                });
            case "Directory":
                let directoryitems: IDirectoryListItem[];
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IDirectoryListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: IDirectoryListItem[] }) => {
                    return items=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            firstName: v.firstName,
                            lastName: v.lastName,
                            mobileNumber: v.mobileNumber,
                            internalNumber: v.internalNumber
                        }
                    ));
                });
            default:
                return null;
        }
      }
}
```

Interfaces are here:

```
export  interface IListItem {
    [key: string]: any;
    id: string;
    title: string;
    modified: Date;
    created: Date;
    modifiedby: string;
    createdby: string;
}




import {IListItem} from "./IListItem";

export interface  INewsListItem extends IListItem {
    newsheader: string;
    newsbody: string;
    expiryDate: Date;
}

import {IListItem} from "./IListItem";

export interface  IAnnouncementListItem extends IListItem {
    announcementBody: string;
    expiryDate: Date;
}


import {IListItem} from "./IListItem";

export interface IDirectoryListItem extends IListItem {
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
        mobileNumber: string;
        internalNumber: string;
}
```

And the consumer method from the TSX component is:

```
 // read items using factory method pattern and sets state accordingly
  private readItemsAndSetStatus(): void {
    this.setState({
      status: "Loading all items..."
    });

    const factory: ListItemFactory = new ListItemFactory();
    factory.getItems(this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, this.props.listName)
    .then((items: IListItem[]) => {
      const keyPart: string = this.props.listName === "GenericList" ? "" : this.props.listName;
        // the explicit specification of the type argument `keyof {}` is bad and
        // it should not be required.
        this.setState<keyof {}>({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${items.length} items`,
          ["Details" + keyPart + "ListItemState"] : {
            items
          },
          columns: buildColumns(items)
        });
    });
  }
```

I paste below the entire TSX just for reference

```
//#region Imports
import * as React from "react";
import styles from "./FactoryMethod.module.scss";
import  { IFactoryMethodProps } from "./IFactoryMethodProps";
import {
  IDetailsListItemState,
  IDetailsNewsListItemState,
  IDetailsDirectoryListItemState,
  IDetailsAnnouncementListItemState,
  IFactoryMethodState
} from "./IFactoryMethodState";
import { IListItem } from "./models/IListItem";
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from "./models/IAnnouncementListItem";
import { INewsListItem } from "./models/INewsListItem";
import { IDirectoryListItem } from "./models/IDirectoryListItem";
import { escape } from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { ListItemFactory} from "./ListItemFactory";
import { TextField } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField";
import {
  DetailsList,
  DetailsListLayoutMode,
  Selection,
  buildColumns,
  IColumn
} from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DetailsList";
import { MarqueeSelection } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/MarqueeSelection";
import { autobind } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Utilities";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
//#endregion


export default class FactoryMethod extends React.Component<IFactoryMethodProps, IFactoryMethodState> {
  constructor(props: IFactoryMethodProps, state: any) {
    super(props);
    this.setInitialState();
  }

  // lifecycle help here: https://staminaloops.github.io/undefinedisnotafunction/understanding-react/

  //#region Mouting events lifecycle

  // the data returned from render is neither a string nor a DOM node.
  // it's a lightweight description of what the DOM should look like.
  // inspects this.state and this.props and create the markup.
  // when your data changes, the render method is called again.
  // react diff the return value from the previous call to render with
  // the new one, and generate a minimal set of changes to be applied to the DOM.
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IFactoryMethodProps> {
    switch(this.props.listName) {
        case "GenericList":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns} />;
        case "News":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsNewsListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns}/>;
        case "Announcements":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsAnnouncementListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns}/>;
        case "Directory":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsDirectoryListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns}/>;
        default:
          return null;
    }
  }

   // invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately AFTER the initial rendering occurs.
   public componentDidMount(): void {
    // you can access any refs to your children
    // (e.g., to access the underlying DOM representation - ReactDOM.findDOMNode).
    // the componentDidMount() method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.
    // if you want to integrate with other JavaScript frameworks,
    // set timers using setTimeout or setInterval,
    // or send AJAX requests, perform those operations in this method.
    this._configureWebPart = this._configureWebPart.bind(this);
    this.readItemsAndSetStatus();
  }

  //#endregion

  //#region Props changes lifecycle events (after a property changes from parent component)
  public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: IFactoryMethodProps): void {
    if(nextProps.listName !== this.props.listName) {
      this.readItemsAndSetStatus();
    }
  }

  //#endregion

  //#region private methods
  private _configureWebPart(): void {
    this.props.configureStartCallback();
  }

  public setInitialState(): void {
    this.state = {
      type: "ListItem",
      status: this.listNotConfigured(this.props)
        ? "Please configure list in Web Part properties"
        : "Ready",
      columns:[],
      DetailsListItemState:{
        items:[]
      },
      DetailsNewsListItemState:{
        items:[]
      },
      DetailsDirectoryListItemState:{
        items:[]
      },
      DetailsAnnouncementListItemState:{
        items:[]
      },
    };
  }

  // reusable inline component
  private ListMarqueeSelection = (itemState: {columns: IColumn[], items: IListItem[] }) => (
      <div>
          <DetailsList
            items={ itemState.items }
            columns={ itemState.columns }
            setKey="set"
            layoutMode={ DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns }
            selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={ true }
            compact={ true }>
          </DetailsList>
      </div>
  )

  // read items using factory method pattern and sets state accordingly
  private readItemsAndSetStatus(): void {
    this.setState({
      status: "Loading all items..."
    });

    const factory: ListItemFactory = new ListItemFactory();
    factory.getItems(this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, this.props.listName)
    .then((items: IListItem[]) => {
      const keyPart: string = this.props.listName === "GenericList" ? "" : this.props.listName;
        // the explicit specification of the type argument `keyof {}` is bad and
        // it should not be required.
        this.setState<keyof {}>({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${items.length} items`,
          ["Details" + keyPart + "ListItemState"] : {
            items
          },
          columns: buildColumns(items)
        });
    });
  }

  private listNotConfigured(props: IFactoryMethodProps): boolean {
    return props.listName === undefined ||
      props.listName === null ||
      props.listName.length === 0;
  }

  //#endregion
}
```

the problem is that its always returnin array of listitems, therefore the react component is only displaying the columns of IListItem, but not display columns of the other interfaces

Update 1:

Trying to do a cast in the  THEN, will result in a duplicate warning for the variable myItems.

[image]

Comment: can you post the code for `buildColumn`?

Comment: I didnt develop that method, it comes from this component. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/detailslist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem because your Promise is returning IListItem[].

If you change the return type of the promise in the getItems method in the factory to any[]. Then do the same to the return type in the 'then' of the getItems method call in the consumer. Then do another switch on the listName in the consumer to cast to the required type there it should work

You can [cast](http://acdcjunior.github.io/typescript-cast-object-to-other-type-or-instanceof.html) using this because you have the list name available in the consumer;

`var myItems = null;
switch(listName) {
    case "GenericList":
        myItems = items as IListItem[];
    case "News":
        myItems = items as INewsListItem[];
    case "Announcements":
        myItems = items as IAnnouncementListItem[];
    case "Directory":
        myItems = items as IDirectoryListItem[];
}`

and then use myItems when you build the columns instead of items

Comment: how can I do the casting on the consumer?

Comment: I updated my original post there with an update, hope it works!

Comment: I understand your idea, but maybe I am misunderstanding, where should it be pasted? please see my Update 1 with the screenshot.

Comment: Updated my answer again, you just needed to declare the var outside of the scope of the switch statement